# Vb.net Network Programming cant add new user to listbox

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, tcp, network-programming

I'm starting to build TCP Server/Client and its protocol, but their are some problem that I could not understand because it less document about it, and it also something relate to cross-threading. I try to avoid illegal cross thread also. As far I do it work on my textbox to update the status from the raiseStatus event, anyway I don't know how to do it with listbox. Normally I cant send and receive all the message I want by using the protocol I build like this: LOGIN:NAK. It mean user NAK login, my program can communicate well with this protocol as I have more to implement. I just got stuck when adding NAK to the listbox1 while Client using this command.

[image: My Server and Client testing image:]

My Server Side Code:

This is my form1 class

```
Public Class Form1

Dim portToListen As Integer = 700
Dim WithEvents manager As ClientMananger
Dim WithEvents M_Client As Client

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    manager = New ClientMananger(Me)
    manager.Listen(portToListen)

End Sub

Private Sub manager_Status(message As String) Handles manager.Status
    txtStatus.Text &= message & vbNewLine
End Sub

End Class
```

And This is my class ClientManager

```
Public Class ClientMananger

Dim tcpListener As TcpListener
Dim listenThread As Thread

Dim clientList As New List(Of Client)

Public Event Status(message As String)
Public Event Connect(client As Client)
Public Event Disconnect(client As Client)

Public Sub Listen(port As Integer)
    tcpListener = New TcpListener(port)

    '' Start thread for listening for new income socket
    listenThread = New Thread(AddressOf ListenProc)
    listenThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ListenProc()
    RaiseStatus("Listen to port ...")

    '' Continously listen to certain port
    tcpListener.Start()
    While True
        Dim incomeClient As New Client(tcpListener.AcceptSocket(), Me)

        '' Income connection has been made
        RaiseStatus("Client attempt to connect ...")

        '' Send welcome message to client
        incomeClient.Send("Welcome to RAMA Hospital Chat Server!")
        clientList.Add(incomeClient)

    End While
End Sub

Public Sub SendAll(client As Client, msg As String)
    For Each c As Client In clientList
        If client IsNot c Then
            c.Send(msg)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub SendTo(sender As Client, rv As String, msg As String)
    For Each c As Client In clientList
        If c.name = rv Then
            c.Send("PRIVATE:" & sender.name & ":" & msg)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

#Region "GUI"
Dim form As Form

'' GUI
Public Sub New(form As Form)
    Me.form = form
End Sub

Private Sub RaiseStatus(txt As String)
    form.Invoke(RaiseStatusInvoker, txt)
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub RaiseStatusDelegate(txt As String)
Private Sub RaiseStatusFunc(txt As String)
    RaiseEvent Status(txt)
End Sub
Private RaiseStatusInvoker As New RaiseStatusDelegate(AddressOf RaiseStatusFunc)

#End Region

End Class
```

And this is the Class Client that i cant make it work, is there anyway i can add my [part(1) mean username that split from the Client] part(1) to the listbox1? I used form1.listbox1.item.add(part(1)) but it not work it does not show any error also.

```
Public Class Client

Dim sck As Socket
Dim msgThread As Thread
Public name As String = ""
Dim parent As ClientMananger
Private _socket As Socket
Private _client As Client

Public Event Status(message As String)

Public Sub New(sck As Socket, parent As ClientMananger)
    Me.sck = sck
    Me.parent = parent

    '' Listen to incoming message
    msgThread = New Thread(AddressOf ReceiveMessage)
    msgThread.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub Send(message As String)
    Dim msgByte() As Byte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)
    sck.Send(msgByte, SocketFlags.None)
End Sub

Private Sub ReceiveMessage()
    Try
        Dim buffer(1000) As Byte
        Dim size As Integer = 0
        Dim msg As String

        Do
            size = sck.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None)
            If size > 0 Then
                msg = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, size)
                HandleMessage(msg)
            End If
        Loop While size > 0
    Catch ex As SocketException
        '' Disconnect
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub HandleMessage(msg As String)

    Dim part() As String = msg.Split(":")
    Dim command As String = part(0).ToUpper()

    If command = "LOGIN" Then
        Me.name = part(1)

        **Form1.listbox1.item.add(part(1))**


        MessageBox.Show(part(1) + " Had been add to the server!!!")
    ElseIf command = "ALL" Then
        parent.SendAll(Me, part(1))
    ElseIf command = "PRIVATE" Then
        parent.SendTo(Me, part(1), part(2))
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

M sorry for posting lot of codes but really cant make this work please help thx you in advance, if you want to get my client side code i can post here.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

After discussion, it is apparent that you cannot access a listbox from a thread in this method, it is unsafe as per [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Instead, you must use the Status event from your ClientManager class. You will need to make three simple edits:

First, update the Status Handler in Form1 to add the text to a new listbox. (Please change listbox name accordingly)

```
Private Sub manager_Status(message As String) Handles manager.Status
    ' CODE ADDED
    ' added code to add the text to a listbox, instead of a textbox
    ListBox1.Items.Add(message)
End Sub
```

Second, Make your ClientManager RaiseStatus sub to be public. It needs to be public, so the Client Class can use it in the third step.

```
' CODE ADDED
' change access modifier to public
Public Sub RaiseStatus(txt As String)
    form.Invoke(RaiseStatusInvoker, txt)
End Sub
```

Last, update the Client Class.HandleMessage sub to use the parent's RaiseStatus Event (the one you just made public in the last step)

```
Private Sub HandleMessage(msg As String)

    Dim part() As String = msg.Split(":")
    Dim command As String = part(0).ToUpper()

    If command = "LOGIN" Then
        Me.name = part(1)

        ' This is unsafe, you cannot access the parent thread this way
        '**Form1.listbox1.item.add(part(1))**

        ' CODE ADDED
        ' this is safe, using the event handler.
        ' parent.RaiseStatus("hello world")
        parent.RaiseStatus(part(1))

    ElseIf command = "ALL" Then
        parent.SendAll(Me, part(1))
    ElseIf command = "PRIVATE" Then
        parent.SendTo(Me, part(1), part(2))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: HI thx for the help syntax error anyway after m changing to form1.listbox1.items.add(part(1)) it so nothing on my listbox1's list item. the MessageBox.show() correctly but the code add without error now but still not display result. i think the real problem is not that error. any tip?